# how to import mySQL data from one table to another where a specific row matches?

Tags: mysql

I have data in 2 different tables and they both have a common row.

One the table where the data should be imported TO is like this:

```
name            country_iso_code            curr_code
Chile           cl
Cameroon        cm
China           cn
Colombia        co
```

As you can see, the "curr_code" row is empty.

The table where the data should be imported FROM is like this:

```
code            curr_code
cl              CLP
cm              XAF
cn              CNY
co              COP
```

What I basically need to do is grab the value "curr_code" where "code" in the FROM table matches "country_iso_code" in the TO table and populate each one of them.

How do I achieve this using mySQL command line?

Thank you very much :)

Comment: [Have you tried anything?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Please [read the manual for `update`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/update.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, [`UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html) statements can contain `JOIN`s just like in standard `SELECT` statements which should be beneficial in this case.

```
UPDATE
    main_table A
    JOIN related_table B
        ON A.country_iso_code = B.code
SET
    A.curr_code = B.curr_code
```